# How can I calculate an original color (with an alpha < 1) based on 2 colours, which have black and white behind it respectively?

Tags: typescript, colors

Apologies for the unclear title, but it's a hard problem to explain. Essentially, I need a Typescript function which accepts two RGB values, both being of the same translucent colour, just with different backgrounds, one being white and the other being black. I understand this isn't a very good explanation, so I have an example.

Let's say you have a colour: `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`. If you were to overlay black (`rgb(0, 0, 0)`) behind it, then pick the resulting colour, you'd get `rgb(128, 0, 0)`. If you did the same for white, you'd get `rgb(255, 127, 127)`. Ideally, you'd have some class, `Color`, with an R, G, B and A value, which this function accepts. So, in code, this would look like:

```
class Color {
    constructor(public r: number, public g: number, public b: number, public a: number = 1) {}
}

const unknownColorWithBlackBg = new Color(128, 0, 0);
const unknownColorWithWhiteBg = new Color(255, 127, 127);

// calculateColor is the function which I am trying to write.
const result = calculateColor(unknownColorWithBlackBg, unknownColorWithWhiteBg);
console.log(result); // Color { R: 255, G: 0, B: 0, A: 0.5 }
```